# How to create multiple store with one frontend(one domain) in opencart?

Tags: opencart

In opencart I want to display one frontend(one domain not sub domain) url with different(multiple) store. I feed product in different store. if the user entered in my domain(url) and purchase some product. Then the quantity decreased any one store.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what a *store* is. Or maybe I am misunderstanding what you understand as a *store*. Nevertheless, when in OpenCart's speech, a *store* is one frontend sitting on one URL (be it a subdomain or subfolder of main domain). From other perspective a *store* can also mean a *storage*. So what do you mean by store?

Answer (score 0):

You can not display multiple store on the same domain. Different domain is required for a new store. You can use sub domains for your new store. And according to your requirement when user will come to your domain he will see only one store which you configured for that domain. If you input same domain for different stores than the user will see only that store which was last entered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way
to create **sub Folder** for different store.

like this

```
 www.yourdomain.com/furniture
    www.yourdomain.com/toys
    www.yourdomain.com/bikes
.
.
.
.
```

for main domain create **index.php** file to **redirect** to relevant store